# jQuery row.child missing on second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, row

I created a table using jQuery. I added a row.child which shall be shown after each parent row. On the first page this works fine. But on the second page it is missing.

```
function format(d) {
    return '' +

            '<i style=";color:#9b9b9b; font-size:10px; Padding-left:50px"> Vertragsart - ' + d[4] + '&nbsp; | &nbsp; Intensität - ' + d[5] + '</i>' +
            '';
}

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('document').ready(function () {
    var oTable = $j('#position_list').DataTable({
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "Zeige _MENU_ Einträge",
            "sSearch": "Suche:",
            "sInfo": "Zeige _START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Zeige _START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(gefiltert aus _MAX_ Datensätzen)",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Nächste",
                "sPrevious": "Vorherige"
            },    
        },
    });

    $j('.parentrow').closest('tr').each(function () {    
        var row = oTable.row(this);
        var data = format(row);
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();   
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't undestand what you mean with "first page" and "second page"

Comment: In the table there is a pagination. On the first page of the table it shows all child rows. When I switch to the second page the chilrow is missing

Comment: Then I think you applied the function after the pagination is created and then the rows are not "there". Try to move you .each() function that create the rows, before calling the dataTable and see if it solve the problem

Comment: Sorry I do not get it, how shall I crete a childrow before creating the table?

Comment: Ahah... you're right, shame on me. The problem remain, you sould call the  row creation after each time a page is displayed, but I'm not DataTable expert enought to know if there's some callback/hook to do it.

Comment: Looking around it look like there is a page event that can help you fire the row creation at the right moment ( https://datatables.net/reference/event/page )

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried a little with this, but I did not manage to let this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using jQuery to select the rows, but jQuery only has access to the rows currently on the DOM. As it was said in the comments, only the  rows of the current page are in the DOM at any given moment, so those are the only rows your code will manipulate.

To run a jQuery selector through the whole table, Datatables API has the [$() method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()). It accepts a jQuery selector that will be run on *all* `tr` elements on the table and their descendant elements, returning a jQuery object like `jQuery(selector)` does.

So you only need to change your jQuery selector for `oTable.$(...)`:

```
oTable.$('.parentrow').closest('tr').each(function () {    
    var row = oTable.row(this);
    var data = format(row);
    row.child(format(row.data())).show();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`drawCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option or [`draw`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) event to call your code every time the table is redrawn.

For example:

```js
$j('#position_list').on('draw.dt', function(){
    $j('.parentrow').closest('tr').each(function(){
        var row = oTable.row(this);
        var data = format(row);
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();   
    });
});
```